# How to Enable Middle Mouse Button in Ubuntu 16.04?

Tags: mouse, hardware

> This question is specific for solutions in given version (16.04). You are free to mark as duplicate, but it is created for solution to latest version user. We cannot simply find any single solution for 16.04 in Google and [feel free to look for it](https://www.google.com.tr/search?q=mmb%20in%20ubuntu&gws_rd=cr&ei=IvkdWLPWIcLeUZHEpegL).

Okay, I try to model things in Blender in Ubuntu 16.04. As you can guess, it uses MMB a lot. One solution is to change MMB to something else, yet Blender uses *nearly all* keys to do anything and you cannot know when you will use one of them.

Regarding this solution, one way is to change MMB to Super key. However, I am using it so often. So, what I am asking is, how to get MMB *really work* in Ubuntu 16.04.

I used `xev` to clear things up. Mouse-wheel-down/up works like a charm, but MMB-click does not respond.

I am using Toshiba Satellite L450, I will give the detailed hardware information below.

Any solution (as answer) or bug-tracker link (as comment) is welcome.

```
00:00.0 Host bridge [0600]: Intel Corporation 2nd Generation Core Processor Family DRAM Controller [8086:0104] (rev 09)
    Subsystem: Toshiba America Info Systems 2nd Generation Core Processor Family DRAM Controller [1179:fc50]
00:01.0 PCI bridge [0604]: Intel Corporation Xeon E3-1200/2nd Generation Core Processor Family PCI Express Root Port [8086:0101] (rev 09)
    Kernel driver in use: pcieport
    Kernel modules: shpchp
00:16.0 Communication controller [0780]: Intel Corporation 6 Series/C200 Series Chipset Family MEI Controller #1 [8086:1c3a] (rev 04)
    Subsystem: Toshiba America Info Systems 6 Series/C200 Series Chipset Family MEI Controller [1179:fc50]
    Kernel driver in use: mei_me
    Kernel modules: mei_me
00:1a.0 USB controller [0c03]: Intel Corporation 6 Series/C200 Series Chipset Family USB Enhanced Host Controller #2 [8086:1c2d] (rev 04)
    Subsystem: Toshiba America Info Systems 6 Series/C200 Series Chipset Family USB Enhanced Host Controller [1179:fc50]
    Kernel driver in use: ehci-pci
00:1b.0 Audio device [0403]: Intel Corporation 6 Series/C200 Series Chipset Family High Definition Audio Controller [8086:1c20] (rev 04)
    Subsystem: Toshiba America Info Systems 6 Series/C200 Series Chipset Family High Definition Audio Controller [1179:fc50]
    Kernel driver in use: snd_hda_intel
    Kernel modules: snd_hda_intel
00:1c.0 PCI bridge [0604]: Intel Corporation 6 Series/C200 Series Chipset Family PCI Express Root Port 1 [8086:1c10] (rev b4)
    Kernel driver in use: pcieport
    Kernel modules: shpchp
00:1c.1 PCI bridge [0604]: Intel Corporation 6 Series/C200 Series Chipset Family PCI Express Root Port 2 [8086:1c12] (rev b4)
    Kernel driver in use: pcieport
    Kernel modules: shpchp
00:1c.5 PCI bridge [0604]: Intel Corporation 6 Series/C200 Series Chipset Family PCI Express Root Port 6 [8086:1c1a] (rev b4)
    Kernel driver in use: pcieport
    Kernel modules: shpchp
00:1c.6 PCI bridge [0604]: Intel Corporation 6 Series/C200 Series Chipset Family PCI Express Root Port 7 [8086:1c1c] (rev b4)
    Kernel driver in use: pcieport
    Kernel modules: shpchp
00:1d.0 USB controller [0c03]: Intel Corporation 6 Series/C200 Series Chipset Family USB Enhanced Host Controller #1 [8086:1c26] (rev 04)
    Subsystem: Toshiba America Info Systems 6 Series/C200 Series Chipset Family USB Enhanced Host Controller [1179:fc50]
    Kernel driver in use: ehci-pci
00:1f.0 ISA bridge [0601]: Intel Corporation HM65 Express Chipset Family LPC Controller [8086:1c49] (rev 04)
    Subsystem: Toshiba America Info Systems HM65 Express Chipset Family LPC Controller [1179:fc50]
    Kernel driver in use: lpc_ich
    Kernel modules: lpc_ich
00:1f.2 SATA controller [0106]: Intel Corporation 6 Series/C200 Series Chipset Family 6 port SATA AHCI Controller [8086:1c03] (rev 04)
    Subsystem: Toshiba America Info Systems 6 Series/C200 Series Chipset Family 6 port SATA AHCI Controller [1179:fc50]
    Kernel driver in use: ahci
    Kernel modules: ahci
00:1f.3 SMBus [0c05]: Intel Corporation 6 Series/C200 Series Chipset Family SMBus Controller [8086:1c22] (rev 04)
    Subsystem: Toshiba America Info Systems 6 Series/C200 Series Chipset Family SMBus Controller [1179:fc50]
    Kernel modules: i2c_i801
01:00.0 VGA compatible controller [0300]: NVIDIA Corporation GF108M [GeForce GT 525M] [10de:0dec] (rev a1)
    Subsystem: Toshiba America Info Systems GF108M [GeForce GT 525M] [1179:fc50]
    Kernel driver in use: nouveau
    Kernel modules: nvidiafb, nouveau
01:00.1 Audio device [0403]: NVIDIA Corporation GF108 High Definition Audio Controller [10de:0bea] (rev a1)
    Subsystem: Toshiba America Info Systems GF108 High Definition Audio Controller [1179:fc50]
    Kernel driver in use: snd_hda_intel
    Kernel modules: snd_hda_intel
08:00.0 USB controller [0c03]: NEC Corporation uPD720200 USB 3.0 Host Controller [1033:0194] (rev 04)
    Subsystem: Toshiba America Info Systems uPD720200 USB 3.0 Host Controller [1179:fc50]
    Kernel driver in use: xhci_hcd
09:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Qualcomm Atheros AR9285 Wireless Network Adapter (PCI-Express) [168c:002b] (rev 01)
    Subsystem: Lite-On Communications Inc AR9285 Wireless Network Adapter (PCI-Express) [11ad:6613]
    Kernel driver in use: ath9k
    Kernel modules: ath9k
0a:00.0 Ethernet controller [0200]: Qualcomm Atheros AR8151 v2.0 Gigabit Ethernet [1969:1083] (rev c0)
    Subsystem: Toshiba America Info Systems AR8151 v2.0 Gigabit Ethernet [1179:fc50]
    Kernel driver in use: atl1c
    Kernel modules: atl1c
```

Comment: Unbelievable that there is still no soluton :-(.

Comment: @copper.hat See the answer below. Blender in Steam works really well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know if this is still an issue for the package in Ubuntu repositories. However, [Blender in Steam](http://store.steampowered.com/app/365670/Blender/) receives middle mouse button inputs pretty well.